# Ensure that a path to a dir is a Django project

Tags: python, django

For the last two days I am struggling with the following question:

Given an absolute path (string) to a directory (inside my file system or the server, it doesn't matter), determine if this dir contains a valid Django project.

First, I thought of looking for the `manage.py` underneath, but what if some user omit or rename this file?

Secondly, I thought of locating the `settings` module but I want the project root, what if the `settings` is 2 or more levels deep?

Third, I thought of locating the (standard) `BASE_DIR` name inside `settings`, but what if the user has not defined it or renamed it?

Is there a way to properly identify a directory as a valid Django project? Am I missing something?

Comment: There's no absolute fail-safe solution to your problem - whatever you test you can think of, it might yields false positives and false negatives.

Comment: *Dumb question*: Is it even possible for a Django project to exist without the manage.py leading to the settings.py? And how would you start a runserver without a manage.py?

Comment: Yes, you can have a project without both **settings.py** and **manage.py**. The **manage.py** is the same as the **django-admin** command line utility. The difference is that **manage.py** adds your project to the `sys.path` and points the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to your **settings.py** module. Your settings module could be named whatever, and to start it you would execute: `django-admin runserver --pythonpath='/home/projects/myproject' --settings=nameofthesettingsmodule`

Comment: @VitorFreitas thank you for the Info.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have just spoke with the fellow-djangonauts via freenode (#django channel) and they said the same thing as @brunodesthuilliers notes.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try is searching/reading the.py files in the directory and match with regex a pattern describing 
the distinctive django main function and package names. 
Might be lucrative, but... eh

Comment: This answer does not, actually, points to a specific direction of solving my problem. Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: OK, I meant write a script/function that seraches in your directory the file containing certain specs. But I hope you found a better easier way.

Answer (score 0):

As [bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) mentioned in the comments, there is no fail-safe solution.

But it depends on what do you need it for. I mean, how strict it has to be (or how good?). I have seen a few times the usage of `PROJECT_DIR` instead of `BASE_DIR`. And about the settings, I've seen single **settings.py** file and several settings files within a **settings** directory.

The main challenge would be Django not having that much hard naming rules for files/modules. You can pretty much name your files whatever, as far as you put the pieces together properly.

If I'm not mistaken, the only hard rule Django has is the **models.py** file. A Django app **must** have a file named **models.py**. But, your Django application doesn't necessarily need to have any app installed.

If you only need a *good enough* solution, I would say **manage.py** is a good candidate. You could double check and open the file and see if there's a django import there. If no **manage.py**, check if there's a **requirements.txt** and check if Django is listed there. If no **requirements.txt**, check for a directory named **requirements** and for text files within.

Something you could do to find some patterns is browsing the [repositories tagged as with "django" tag on GitHub](https://github.com/topics/django). Maybe use their API and clone all repositories (it will only list the top 2000 repos) to your local machine or to a server. Clone some `rails`, `javascript`, etc. repos as well and write your code step by step. Just search for a **manage.py**, if the result is satisfatory, that's it. If not, add a couple of more rules and test against the cloned repositories until you find a good enough solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Vitor but I cannot accept it since it does not gives a straightforward way of figuring out my question. There are a lot of assumptions that have to be made and I'll end up with a bunch of code just to figure out if a dir is a Django one or not. Maybe I am asking an unanswered question... I'll leave it open, for future reference/edits, since there is not other similar in SO.
Thanks again for your effort, really appreciate it :)